# How do I only have one task in my application?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, replace, reinstall

This is my Main Activity in Manifest:
[Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLnY0.png)
And I has Receiver to detect my app is replaced(re-install)
[onReceive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPyQE.png)
[re open app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTDBL.png)
After detect re-install, I re-open app but has issue
-Whenever press Home then click icon app to open, always create new task and old task is not removed
=> My expect is open old task, when press Home key then click icon app
Plz help me resolve it! Thank you!

Comment: `And I has Receiver to detect my app is replaced(re-install)` Interesting. Didnt know that was possible. Can you tell how you did that?

Comment: Instead of linking to image of text, can you please paste the relevant code in your question?

Comment: Hi @blackapps, "detect my app is replaced" by Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED

Comment: Sorry @C.Peck, I'm not enough 100 Reputation to show Images.

Answer (score 0):

Set the launchMode on the Activity in your manifest to be `singleTask`.  This will make it so that if an existing Activity exists when you try to launch it, it will find it and call its onNewIntent instead of creating a new instance.

Please note that this will only work if the framework hasn't destroyed the old activity for resources yet.  Which is unlikely if you quickly go back to that app, but can happen if you take a long time or open resource intensive apps.

Comment: Tks @Gabe Sechan, I will try that!